# Dual space of a closed subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading Girault and Raviart's book concerning Finite Element Methods for Navier-Stokes equations, and they use in the proof of one result, the following argument:

As $V=\{v\in H_0^1(\Omega)^N; {\rm div}\;v=0\; \text{in}\;\Omega\}$ is closed in  $H_0^1(\Omega)^N$, then V* (dual space of V) can be identified with a subspace of $H^{-1}(\Omega)^N$, where $\Omega$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

My question is: why do we need that $V$ must be closed in $H_0^1(\Omega)^N$ (which it is) to get the isomorphism between V* and a subspace of $H^{-1}(\Omega)^N$? In fact, by using Hahn-Banach theorem we can build such isomorphism.  (Remember that in order to use Hahn-Banach theorem, we just need a subspace of a vector space)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample to your claim, notice that $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is a subspace of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ (although it is *not* closed), and its dual is $D'(\Omega)$ (the space of all distributions on $\Omega$) which is not a subset of $H^{-1}(\Omega)$.

Note that to use the Hahn-Banach theorem, you need a sublinear function which is defined on the whole space and which dominates the functional you wish to extend on its domain. Apparently no such function exists for some distributions (for instance, the Dirac delta in dimension higher than 2).

Comment: It should be noted though, that $\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ is a bit special because one usually gives it a different (finer) topology than the obvious one it has as the dual space of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: @kahen Sure, but I don't think that changes the situation here.

Comment: @Ian: It's still not answered my question. I was able to prove the argument given before but I don't use the fact that $V$ is a closed set of $H_0^1(\Omega)$. I only use the fact that $V$ is a subspace of this. To show that, I use Hahn-Banach theorem for normed spaces. In this case you use as a sublinear function the given by the norm of the space (you can find this result in Brezis' book). So, in this case I can formulate my question in a more general form: Is it true that if $V$ is a closed subset of a Hilbert space  $H$, then $V^*$ is identified with a subspace of $H^*$?

Comment: @NepalDraus The problem is that the norm of the space may not dominate a functional which is bounded only on a "small" subspace. For example, you shouldn't expect the Dirac delta to be dominated by the Sobolev norm unless the Sobolev space embeds into $L^\infty$. In particular, for $H^1$ in dimension 3 or higher (I think also dimension 2, but I don't want to deal with technicalities), you can have a smooth function with $f(0)=1$ and yet $\| f \|_{H^1} < \varepsilon$ for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @NepalDraus So I think I have answered the question "why does the result not necessarily follow if $V$ is just a subspace?", which seems to be half of your question. I don't know how to answer the question "why does the result follow if $V$ is a closed subspace?"

Comment: @Ian : Thanks for your answer. I have a remark concerning the Hahn-Banach extension theorem. Let E a normed space and F a subspace of E endowed with the E-norm. If you have any linear continuous functional (continuous with the E-norm) defined on F, you **always** can extend this functional to a functional defined over the whole space E. Moreover, the norms of the both functionals are the same. The problem with your example of the delta the Dirac is that this distribution does not belong to $H^1$.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, I agree with your example using the space $C_0^\infty$ as a subspace of $H_0^1$. As you say, in fact, my question is oriented in the sense of how to show that we really need that $V$ must be closed. If in the future, you know some reference of this or any news, please don't hesitate to tell me. Thanks!

Comment: @NepalDraus You've pointed out a real problem, which is that the functionals I had in mind are not even bounded with respect to the $H^1$ norm on $C^\infty_c$. Maybe there is a fully constructive proof in the closed case, which is not constructive otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

For the identification (or related) see Theorem 4.9 in Rudin1991 ("Functional Analysis")

However, this identification (and also the closedness of $V$) need not be invoked for the particular result. I assume you are talking about Corollary 2.5 in Girault and Raviart. Namely, the Hahn-Banach theorem provides that any functional $\mathbf{f}\in V'$ that vanishes on $\mathscr{V}$ can be extended to a functional $\hat{\mathbf{f}}\in H^{-1}(\Omega)^N$ that vanishes on $\mathscr{V}$. Therefore, $\hat{\mathbf{f}}$ vanishes on $V$ and hence $\mathbf{f}$ vanishes on $V$ since $\hat{\mathbf{f}} = \mathbf{f}$ on $V$. This is the desired result. Now, the closedness of $V$ (i.e. $V$ being a Banach space) can be only needed if you want to invoke exactly the result (2.14) in Girault and Raviart, which is stated for Banach spaces. However, (2.14) holds also for general normed spaces.